# Segmentation fault on memcpy in C

Tags: c, memory, segmentation-fault

I am working on a little project where I am trying to emulate a CPU declaring and assigning values to variables, so far so good. So I defined the following structures for my CPU and Memory.

CPU (Can only keep track of 3 variables)

```
typedef struct variableReference{
    char *tag;
    void *reference;
}variableReference;

typedef struct CPU{
    int variableCounter;
    int instructionPointer;
    variableReference dataDictionary[3];
    void *currentContext;
}CPU;
```

Memory (and it's creation function). By the way, CPU.currentContext points to the memory.base on startup, then it can change.

```
typedef struct Memory{
    void *base;
    int size;
}Memory;

Memory memory_create(int size){
    Memory newMemory;
    newMemory.base = malloc(size);
    newMemory.size = size;
    return newMemory;
}
```

So the first thing I do is allocate a block of memory and keep track of it using the CPU current context pointer. I already have a function that asks the cpu to declare a variable (variables can only be integer) and another one that asks the cpu to assign that variable a value (int). To do this, I keep track of a limited amount of variable names and references in cpu.dataDictionary.

The variable declaring seems to work just fine, but the problem occurs when I try to assign that variable a value, which I do like this (e.g. a = 4;):

```
cpu_assignVariable(&myCPU,"a",4,&myMemory);
```

At that time, in my cpu.dataDictionary I have this in the first record {"a",0x804b008}, so all I should have to do is look for that position in the allocated memory block, and copy the value (integer 4), like this:

```
void *reference = cpu_dereferenceVariable(*myCPU,tag); // gets a's address

memory_write(reference,1,sizeof(value),(void *) value); // writes the value
```

now the memory_write implementation, where I get the Segmentation Fault (I have an offset of 1 because on the "reference" position I previously wrote the variable name:

```
int memory_write(void *base, int offset,int size,void *value){
    memcpy(base+offset,value,size);
    return 0;
}
```

I'd expect the memory block to look like this |a|0|0|0|4|x|x|...|x|, but all I get is a segmentation fault error. Any ideas???

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: In C, adding N to a pointer adds N * sizeof(pointer type) to the address.  You cannot take sizeof(void) so I am surprised this compiles.

Comment: @stark: Many compilers will treat `void *` arithmetic as `uint8_t *` arithmetic.

Comment: GCC certainly permits arithmetic on `void` pointers; presumably Clang does too, to be compatible with GCC if for no other reason.  However, GCC acknowledges the arithmetic on `void` pointers is an extension over the standard and doesn't do it if you require `-pedantic` compliance.  I'm not sure which other compilers support it.

Comment: @stark, the curious thing is that if I set a watch on (base+offset) I get 0x804b009, which is exactly base + 1. Can I assume this is working ? Thanks for your answer

Comment: @GuillermoGruschka: You can assume it works _on your system_. Your code however does not fully comply to the C standard, which means that your code won't compile (and thus not work) everywhere. Put simply: if you are targetting a specific system/environment then you can assume this works, if not: back to the drawing board. PS: negative pointer arithmetic with negatives and a negative size argument for `memcpy` don't make sense, so perhaps consider changing the argument types of `offset` and `size` to `size_t` to reflect this

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem, Thanks for your answer!. This is just a school project, and it is not intended to run on different environments (we all use a Virtual Machine for that purpose). I will use size_t as you suggested, but I am still getting segmentation fault on that line. Any ideas? If you need further information just ask. Thanks again

Comment: @GuillermoGruschka: I haven't looked into your code in any level of detail, but I will say this: in your `memory_create` function, you are allocating the `base` pointer as a `char` pointer. Why not declare it as such? You can cast the pointer to anything you want later on... What you're doing with that `myCPU` variable is also a tad weird: passing its address `cpu_assignVariable(&myCPU` one time, and then passing it dereferenced (`cpu_dereferenceVariable(*myCPU,tag)`)... that just makes it all quite complex and just... well, odd. I'd have to see more code, but that's a source of errors

Comment: What does cpu_dereferenceVariable return when it does not find the variable?  Do you check for that case?